# $\int_A f = \int_A g \implies f = g$ a.e.

Tags: measure-theory, proof-verification, lebesgue-integral, almost-everywhere

Consider a measure space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mu)$ and let $f,g: \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ be $\mathcal{F}$-measurable integrable functions. If

$$\int_A f d \mu = \int_A g d \mu$$

for all $A \in \mathcal{F}$, then $f = g$ $\mu$-a.e.

Here is the proof my course notes provide:

It is sufficient to prove that $\mu\{f < g\} = 0 = \mu\{g < f\}$. By symmetry, we only prove the first equality.

Put $$h:= (g-f)I_{\{g > f\}}$$

Then $$\int_\Omega h d\mu = \int_{\{f<g\}}(g-f) = 0$$ since $f,g$ are integrable functions. Since $h \geq 0$, it follows that $h = 0$ a.e. and thus $\mu\{g > f\} 
 \leq \mu\{h \neq 0\} = 0$. This ends the proof.

> My question: Can we generalise this to integrable functions $f,g:
>  \Omega \to [-\infty, \infty]$ (note the change of codomain).

I think the proof generalises: the function $h$ is well defined because we can only have $\infty - (-\infty) = \infty$. Is this correct?

Comment: How do you define integration over this kind of functions? In particular what is the integral of $\infty \cdot \chi_{\{0\}}$?

Comment: $1_0$? Do you mean $I_\emptyset?$

Comment: @Math_QED I presume that they mean the characteristic function of the singleton set containing $0$.  In other words, what is $$\int_{\Omega} f(x)\,\mathrm{d}\mu $$ when $f$ is the function $$f(x) = \begin{cases} \infty, & x= 0 \\ 0, & x\ne 0. \end{cases} $$

Comment: I define $\int_\Omega \alpha I_A d \mu := \alpha \mu(A)$ where $0. \infty = 0 = \infty. 0$. So, assuming lebesgue measure (and singeltons have measure $0$), that integral would be equal to $0$.

Comment: Yes, if we restrict to $f<g$, and both $f(x),g(x)$ are infinite, we must have $f(x)=-\infty,\ g(x)=+\infty$, so $h$ indeed seems well defined.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. So you agree that the theorem generalises without changing the proof?